# How does one track down the error message Error in deparse1(call)

Tags: r, arules

This code worked great:

```
Data <- read.csv("./input/DataSet05.csv", header=T, colClasses='factor')

Groups <- DataSet05[6:12]

Groups[Groups=="0"] <- NA

rules <- apriori(Groups, parameter = list(ext = FALSE, minlen=2, supp=0.2, conf=0.5))

inspect(rules)
```

I updated my box yesterday, now I get the following error.

> Error in deparse1(call) : could not find function "deparse1"

Also, I added some new packages.

My thoughts are the update killed the ability of arules to work.

QUESTION

How do I track down this error message to identify why the R code no longer runs?

Comment: When you say you "updated your box," what does that mean exactly? Did you install a new/different version of R? Or any packages? What version of R and the `arules` pacakge are you running? Are you using a version of R that's older than 4.0?

Comment: `deparse1` is a function in base R that was added in R-4.0.0, so not finding it suggests that if your code previously worked, either it used to be in R >= 4 or you had the `backports` package installed previously. If you're on R >= 4, then that error makes no sense; if you're on R < 4, then install the `backports` package and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Hi MrFlick,  I did update using R Studio GUI. I also installed two packages by compressed file using R Studio GUI. I tried today to install arules and then update, both using R Studio GUI. Same error message.

Comment: Hi r2evans, I will try installing backports and reply back with results. Thanks.

Comment: VERSION
stephen@LENOVO-SSD ~/Desktop $ R --version
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Comment: I used the R Studio GUI to check updates. Nothing found.

Then, I used the console tab using update.packages(ask = FALSE) and many updates are found and installed using the console.

I am still getting the same error message.

I then installed backports. This time I used the R Studio GUI.

Still getting the error message.

Error in deparse1(call) : could not find function "deparse1"

QUESTIONS
Why is R Studio GUI not finding updates but update.packages(ask = FALSE) from the console is finding many updates?

How do I track down the error message?


Thanks,

-SHD